# »Missing number, treated as zero.« in graphics with invoice

Tags: fontspec, invoice

I’m on Debian’s texlive 2013.20130530-1.

My minimal test document is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{invoice}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error, using xelatex:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\char 
l.32 \catcode
           `\*=11
```

The [only reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/TZyOYGcdzmg) to something similar that I found is from 2001. I guess the analysis applies to this case, too. I also tried replacing `invoice` with all packages it uses (`graphics`, `fp`, etc), but the error did not appear. I didn’t find anything special happening to ` in `invoice`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug of `invoice`. It loads `fp` by using `input`.

line 152:

```
\input{fp}
```

That means it loads the file `fp.tex` which is designed for plain TeX.

If you change the line 152 from `\input{fp}` to `\RequirePackage{fp}` everything works well.